# Why Published Test Results link is not working?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, aspnetzero

My pipeline runs, detects my test results, and claims to upload them. However, the link gives me a 404. This is the first time I've tried to use this task in the pipeline. According to the Microsoft documentation, this should "just work". Do I have to set something up, such as the LogStore?

Here is my task output:

```
    2020-09-10T13:09:46.0788962Z ##[section]Starting: PublishTestResults 2020-09-10T13:09:46.0796709Z ============================================================================== 
    
    2020-09-10T13:09:46.0797094Z Task : Publish Test Results 
    2020-09-10T13:09:46.0797403Z Description : Publish test results to Azure Pipelines 
    2020-09-10T13:09:46.0797695Z Version : 2.171.0 
    2020-09-10T13:09:46.0797952Z Author : Microsoft Corporation 
    2020-09-10T13:09:46.0798351Z Help : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results 
    2020-09-10T13:09:46.0798797Z 
    
    ============================================================================== 
    
    2020-09-10T13:09:47.0324426Z [command]/usr/bin/dotnet --version 
    2020-09-10T13:09:47.0324719Z 3.1.401 
    2020-09-10T13:09:47.7287270Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore 
    2020-09-10T13:09:47.7408902Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore 
    2020-09-10T13:09:47.9409482Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results 
    2020-09-10T13:09:48.0169350Z Publishing test results to test run '20'. 
    2020-09-10T13:09:48.0201815Z 
    TestResults To Publish 7, Test run id:20 
    2020-09-10T13:09:48.0246833Z 
    Test results publishing 7, remaining: 0. Test run id: 
    20 2020-09-10T13:09:48.6828668Z 
    
    **Published Test Run : https://dev.azure.com/tmc-it/tmconsulting-us-com/_TestManagement/Runs?runId=20&_a=runCharts. 
    2020-09-10T13:09:49.1592828Z **
    
    TestRunPublisher.IsTestRunFailed: Getting test run summary with run id: 20 using stats api 
    2020-09-10T13:09:49.1925388Z 
    TestRunPublisher.IsTestRunFailed: checking if test run is failed using run summary input 
    2020-09-10T13:09:49.1926158Z Number of failed tests which are non-flaky is: 1 
    2020-09-10T13:09:49.1966815Z 
    
    Failed Results are published 
    2020-09-10T13:09:49.2098192Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results 
    2020-09-10T13:09:49.2099790Z ##[section]Finishing: PublishTestResults
```

There should be all the tests in this URL : https://dev.azure.com/tmc-it/tmconsulting-us-com/_TestManagement/Runs?runId=20&_a=runCharts but it shows 404 page instead.

Comment: Please confirm two points. 1. In the log, the date is 2020-09-10, are you sure that this is the latest log? 2. Please check your access level. I found if I visit the Published Test Run link with the stakeholder access level, it will show 404 page, and the basic access level can visit the link without problem.

Comment: @Miao Tian-MSFT, Thank you for your response..

 I have also the latest tests published on Azure but Gives the same results as mentioned and I dont think its access level issue as I'm also an administrator for the same.

Comment: Can you try opening the Runs page under test plan and find the run with ID 20? If you can find it, click to open it and see if you have the same problem. To make it clear, I will add an answer with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Runs page under test plan and find the run with ID 20. If you can find it, double click it.
Or just enter the Run ID and click `Go` button. It will lead to the same URL.

[image]

Please check if there will be the same problem. If there is, please share some screenshots.